# Assert different conditions on fields from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, case

Let's say I have a dimension and a fact table:

```
SELECT     
      LAST_DAY(TO_Date((f.Date),'MON-YYYY')) "MonthYear",
      f.Region,
      d.Formula as "Molecule",
      d.product_name,
      d.supplier.
      SUM(f.Sales) as "Sales",
      SUM(f.ext_units) as "ext_Units",
      SUM(f.units) "Units",
      SUM(f.ext_units) / SUM(f.units) as "Product_units"

CASE 
      WHEN d.Formula = 'ABC:CBA' THEN 'ABC' 
      WHEN d.Formula = 'DEF-FED' THEN 'DEF' 
      WHEN d.Formula = 'xyz;zyx' THEN 'xyz'
      ELSE d.Formula 

END AS "Molecule"
      
FROM Fact.Sales f
INNER JOIN DM_Product d on f.P-Code = d.P-Code

WHERE
     f.Region = 'Mars'
     AND d.Supplier = 'Simpsons' 
     AND d.Formula in ('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','BDHJK',
    'FGL','MNP','RSTU', 'KCL', 'xyz', 'UWX', 
'xyz;zyx', 'DEF-FED', 'ABC:CBA')

GROUP BY f.Date,
         f.Region,
         d.Formula,
         d.product_name,
         d.supplier
```

so, basically what I intend to do is to get all these Molecules from the Product Dimension table and find their relevant sales. but the puzzle is I have two different set of conditions:

1. to look into to all the two syllabuses *formulas* and aggregate them with equivalent one syllabi *formula* to find aggregate sales.
2. Find "*Product_units*" using `SUM(f.ext_units) / SUM(f.units)` as per my code.
   **`(f.units)` does have 0 values.**

As I put for the 1st condition, I used `CASE WHEN` and it works perfect to find the 2 syllabuses formulas and plug them to relevant 1 syllabi formula but for the second condition that I need to know **how to make sure that f.units <> 0** that is checking if `SUM(f.units) <> 0` THEN `SUM(f.ext_units) /SUM(f.units)` ELSE `0` ?

Comment: Snowflake or SQL Server? They are quite different products, please only tag the one you want a solution for.

Comment: You're much more likely to get assistance if you provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results, and a query that is cut down to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue.